# Access denied with viewing group contacts

Tags: permissions

I have a drupal 7 civicrm site just upgraded to 4.7.8 and I am user 1 for drupal and civicrm.

I have two instances where I cannot get past access denied

contacts/manage groups/select group and then when I press to see contacts it says access denied.

The same happens when I go to draft email and want to view the draft email.

I have a couple of other sites and this is not happening. These two use the same theme however so I think it is something theme related (possibly module therefore). I have disabled the theme and it did not resolve. But When in site maintenance node instead of access denied I get the site in maintenance mode page.

I'm not a developer so am not quite sure where to start in trouble shooting this. My permission credential is not being passed from page to page but I'm not sure why....

If anyone has any thoughts on where to start with this that would be great.

Thanks you.
Caroline

Answer (score 1):

Ah I found an answer in the old forum here https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=27010.0